# Making a GIF from a Video

Tags: macos, video

I have a video clip that I want to convert to an animated GIF. I used [GIFBrewery](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/gifbrewery/id435989461).

But I couldn't figure out how to make a GIF that's the proper speed. The default preview they showed had way too many frames missing, so I increased the frame count. But once I did that, the GIF played way too slowly. How do I make the GIF speed simply the same speed as the original video?

I also used MPEG Streamclip to export to PNGs so I can use GIMP to create the GIF. Same problem, couldn't create a proper speed GIF.

Comment: Increase the frame speed.

Comment: @Timothy Mueller-Harder how?

Answer (score 1):

In the "gif settings" box there's a value for "frame delay" which defaults at 100. This is the time in milliseconds between each frame.  The small it is, the faster the gif will animate.

Frame delay of 100 is 10 frames per second.  If you have 30 frames per second, use 33 as the frame delay.  If you have 15 frames per second, use 67 as the frame delay.

Or just change the "frame delay" value until it looks right - smaller for faster speed, bigger for slower speed.

There's a pretty good overview of how to use the app in this article:

http://www.macworld.com/article/1164864/how_to_create_an_animated_gif_from_a_video_clip.html

Also note that the preview inside the app is limited to 10 frames per second or slower - if it looks slow inside the app, test it out in a real browser.

Answer (score 0):

[GifRocket](http://www.gifrocket.com/) creates a gif in the proper speed.

The problem is that it doesn't have any configuration to change speed, but you could use [Adapter](http://www.macroplant.com/adapter/) and convert a video with the configuration you want and then convert it to `.gif` using GifRocket.

Best thing is that both apps are free.